# Require a path variable

Tags: path

Good morning!

Does anyone know if there's a way to require a path variable in a page?

I have a page in EE (3.3.0) such as this:

www.bakers.com/site/cookies/oatmeal/

Where "oatmeal" is a title of an entry.  So when I link to it, I do this:

{title}

Works great.  But if someone just navigates to www.bakers.com/site/cookies/ it will just list all of the cookies in a big long list.  I'd like to present either a 404 or a custom page.

Thoughts?

Not sure if this is a job for hidden templates...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for the previous post.

You just need to add require_entry="yes" in you channel:entries tag -

```
  {exp:channel:entries channel="cookies" require_entry="yes" }
     {title}
  {/exp:channel:entries}
```

This parameter tells the channel tag that it should expect the URL to contain a valid entry ID or a valid URL title. If an ID is not found in the URL, the tag will not display any data.

Comment: nice welcome :)